# SQL - Finding rows with duplicate values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that includes these columns:

```
Nameplate
Model
Segment
```

A sample table looks like:

```
Nameplate  Model  Segment
Acura      ILX    Small Lux Car
Audi       Q5     Compact Lux Car
Audi       Q5     Mid Lux Car
Audi       SQ5    Compact Lux Car
```

I need to find all `Nameplate, Model` combinations with multiple `Segments`.

In the above table, I need it to return:

```
Audi       Q5     Compact Lux Car
Audi       Q5     Mid Lux Car
```

I thought the following would work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   [Nameplate], [Model], [Segment]
FROM 
   dbo.[Weighted Extract]
GROUP BY 
   [Nameplate], [Model], [Segment]
HAVING 
   COUNT([Segment]) > 1;
```

The above code only returns combinations with multiple `Nameplate, Model`, and `Segment` rows.  This should be easier than I am making it, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT [Nameplate], [Model]
FROM dbo.[Weighted Extract]
GROUP BY [Nameplate], [Model]
HAVING COUNT(distinct [Segment]) > 1;
```

Comment: Doesn't return `Segment` column as desired.

Comment: That was it!  I was trying to add Segment to the SELECT statement and it was erroring.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Martin - you are correct, but Kaidjin's code at least shows me where the duplicates are.  Showing the Segment would be nice but was not critical for my needs at this point.

Comment: So why tell us "I need it to return" a column that you don't actually need then? Or not accept one of the answers that answers the full question you asked. Including this "nice" aspect?

Comment: The OP states "I need to find all Nameplate, Model combinations with multiple Segments". -> doesn't say he needs segments. Besides, how do you return the segment of a group with multiple segments ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT [Nameplate], [Model], [Segment]
FROM dbo.[Weighted_Extract] we1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[Weighted_Extract] we2
    WHERE we1.Nameplate = we2.Nameplate
    AND   we1.Model = we2.Model
    AND   we1.Segment <> we2.Segment
);
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6adb3/4/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should work from sqlserver 2005+:

```
;WITH X AS
(
  SELECT [Nameplate], [Model], [Segment], 
         count(*) over (partition by [Nameplate], [Model]) cnt
  FROM dbo.[Weighted Extract]
)
SELECT [Nameplate], 
       [Model], 
       [Segment] 
FROM X 
WHERE cnt > 1
```